# What is the smallest Awg stranded wire that can be used in a house on 20amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, code-compliance, gauge

Smallest stranded wire that can be used with 20 Amp breakers

Answer (score 4):

Generally what you're asking is NEC 240.4(D)(6) limits the maximum overcuurent protection of #12 AWG of solid or stranded to 20A. The next size smaller #14 is limited to 15A.

But that's just "Mostly True", the NEC is full of details. Here's what is says:

> **(D) Small Conductors**. Unless specifically permitted in 240.4(E) or (G), the overcurrent protection shall not exceed that required by
> 240.4(D)(1) through (D)(8) after any correction factors for ambient temperature and number of conductors have been applied.

> (4) 14 AWG Copper, 15 amperes

> (6) 12 AWG Copper, 20 amperes

Ah, but what do (E) and (G) say?

(E) covers tap conductors that almost never apply to DIY, and (G) gives a table of applications where 240.4(D) doesn't apply.

[image]

For those listed applications if your terminals and wire meet 75°C requirements then table 310.16 says you could use wire as small as #14 copper for the listed applications. (For examples THWN wire meets the requirement, NM "romex" doesn't because type NM is limited to 60°C column of 310.16.)

So #14 copper is the smallest allowed for some circuits, but for most circuits the answer is #12 on a 20A.

Answer (score 2):

12 gauge for the house circuits. The wires from the panel to the receptacle/light box.

Bought devices(lights, stuff that is plugged in) that has UL/CSA listing/label can have smaller gauge wires if the manufacturer supplies them, the cord that came with the light.

Answer (score 1):

A 20A breaker requires 12Ga copper or 10Ga aluminum (or larger).